# how does QueryDict split HttpRequest query

Tags: python, django, httprequest

Example:

```
>>> from django.http import QueryDict
>>> q = QueryDict('a=x&b=y&c=z')
>>> q
<QueryDict: {u'a': [u'x'], u'c': [u'z'], u'b': [u'y']}>
>>> q = QueryDict('a=x&b=y&c=z+1')
>>> q
<QueryDict: {u'a': [u'x'], u'c': [u'z 1'], u'b': [u'y']}>
>>>                                  ^
```

Why is the '+' replaced with a space?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005676/urls-and-plus-signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` is reserved as shorthand notation for space.

To represent `+`, use `%2b`:

```
>>> QueryDict('a=x&b=y&c=z%2b1')
<QueryDict: {u'a': [u'x'], u'c': [u'z+1'], u'b': [u'y']}>
```