# Testing request parameters in Django ("+" behaves differently)

Tags: python, django

I have a Django View that uses a query parameter to do some content filtering. Something like this:

```
/page/?filter=one+and+two
/page/?filter=one,or,two
```

I have noticed that Django converts the `+` to a space (`request.GET.get('filter')` returns `one and two`), and I´m OK with that. I just need to adjust the `split()` function I use in the View accordingly.

**But...**

When I try to test this View, and I call:

```
from django.test import Client
client = Client()
client.get('/page/', {'filter': 'one+and+two'})
```

`request.GET.get('filter')` returns `one+and+two`: with plus signs and no spaces. Why is this?

I would like to think that `Client().get()` mimics the browser behaviour, so what I would like to understand is why calling `client.get('/page/', {'filter': 'one+and+two'})` is not like browsing to `/page/?filter=one+and+two`. **For testing purposes it should be the same in my opinion**, and in both cases the view should receive a consistent value for filter: be it with `+` or with spaces.

What I don´t get is why there are two different behaviours.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The plusses in a query string are the normal and correct encoding for spaces. This is a historical artifact; the [form value encoding for URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type) differs ever so slightly from encoding other elements in the URL.

Django is responsible for decoding the query string back to key-value pairs; that decoding includes decoding the URL percent encoding, where a `+` is decoded to a space.

When using the test client, you pass in *unencoded data*, so you'd use:

```
client.get('/page/', {'filter': 'one and two'})
```

This is then encoded to a query string for you, and subsequently decoded again when you try and access the parameters.

Comment: Ok, so I have to use `client.get('/page/', {'filter': 'one two three'})` in my tests, as I was doing. My concern was that this doesn't seem consistent (if `Client` is mimicking a browser). It should be `client.get('/page/', {'filter': 'one+two+three'})` in my opinion. But I guess this is how `Client` is designed. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @eillarra: it is consistent with how the data is presented in a Django view. How the data is passed around (encoded in a query string), doesn't really matter there.

Comment: Django aims to give you 'nice' Python representations of the data you work with and hides the various peculiar HTML and HTTP representations where possible. Saves a lot of mental effort, actually, because getting encoding and decoding right is painful.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the test client (actually, RequestFactory) runs `django.utils.http.urlencode` on your data, resulting in `filter=one%2Band%2Btwo`. Similarly, if you were to use `{'filter': 'one and two'}`, it would be converted to `filter=one%20and%20two`, and would come into your view with spaces.

If you really absolutely must have the pluses in your query string, I believe it may be possible to manually override the query string with something like: `client.get('/page/', QUERY_STRING='filter=one+and+two')`, but that just seems unnecessary and ugly in my opinion.

Comment: The only thing I want to do is to write my tests like a 'real' request. I could write `client.get('/page/', {'filter': 'one two three'})` in the test, and it will pass because the view receives `one two three` in this case. But it doesn't seem logical.

Comment: @eillarra, Plus sign is special case in query string, it means space character. That's why Django performs the conversion. Refer:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1 and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005676/urls-and-plus-signs  
So I think it's OK to just use 'one two three' in test cases.

Comment: `django.utils.http.urlencode()` produces `filter=one+and+two` because that's the correct encoding for spaces in a query parameter.

Comment: In other words, there is no need to do any manually override anything here; the `QUERY_STRING` value will *already* be encoded correctly.