# Base64 Encoded URL Parameter "+" Missing in Django HTTP GET

Tags: django, http, get, base64

I have sent a GET WSGIRequest to django server with an Base64 encoded parameter.  The encoded parameter has a "+" character inside.

Django 1.9.6 gets my url correctly, but when it tried to parse the parameters from url into GET QueryDict, the parameter is incorrectly built:  the "+" is replaced with SPACE.

Is this possibly a bug of Django, or it intentionally parsed the parameter this way?

Is there any solution please?

A screenshot is provided here for your better reference. 
[Screenshot of IDE Debuger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulEBz.png)

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703930/testing-request-parameters-in-django-behaves-differently

Comment: Hi Newtt, thank you for your comment. Now I know Django intentionally did it this way.  So I guess the solution would be to manually replace the SPACE in the base64 parameter with "+", right?