# solr url filter query construction

Tags: solr

I need to make a solr query through url and I do:

Query has to be

name:john AND id:5

Filter Query

byr:75 OR byr:90

I tried doesn't seem to work

```
  url.....?q=name:john+id:5&fq=(byr:75 OR byr:90)
```

I know that AND is + but what is the symbol for OR? Couldn't find much online so seeking help here

Comment: Read this: https://lucidworks.com/blog/why-not-and-or-and-not/  (no prefix symbol means OR)

Comment: If this is truly a URL (which it appears to be) then the ```+``` will be interpreted as a space.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005676/urls-and-plus-signs

Answer (score 0):

`+` is not the symbol for AND - it means that the clause is required for the document to be considered a match. And in this case, it seems to only be the escape code for a space in the URL.

Use " AND " if both clauses are required (the default behavior is affected by `q.op` and `mm` if you're using dismax).

Answer (score 0):

**fq=byr:(75 90)** will give you a search against **byr** field with two possible values. This is sort of described right at the end of [the Standard Query Parser documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser#TheStandardQueryParser-GroupingTermstoFormSub-Queries).

I would recommend reading that whole article. And don't confuse **+** sign used in the query and **+** used in URL to escape special characters.