# Keep the + in a get request string

Tags: php, laravel, get, request

I'm working on a website for parkos where clients can make reservations with there email but some clients use a plus sign in their email.

for example:

```
test+parkos@gmail.com
```

Now if for example clients wanted to see their reservations I'm creating a get request in the url and you would get something like this:

```
http://test.com/reservations/?email=test+parkos@gmail.com&number=GH76G
```

after that I'm trying to retrieve the email and echo it:

```
$email = request()->input('email');
{{!! $email!!}}
```

Than If I try to view on it my webpage this is what I get:

```
test parkos@gmail.com
```

The + sign is gone and I was wondering if there is a way to keep the + sign.

Comment: Use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and urldecode

Comment: @Thamilan  request()->input use urldecode for you

Comment: Thanks I'll try that

Comment: @Mixedfruitjuice how did you get the http://test.com/reservations/?email=test+parkos@gmail.com&number=GH76G
 url from?

Comment: It's an url I made up that that looks like the url I'm using for the website

Comment: yeah but how you creating this url inside laravel? cause its autmatic urlencode if for you  take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-url function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Url is wrong because + sign has its own meaning according to CGI standard. It means a whitespace.

Right url shold be

http://test.com/reservations/?email=test%2Bparkos@gmail.com&number=GH76G

As explained in [URLs and plus signs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005676/urls-and-plus-signs)

```
+ becomes %2B
space becomes %20
```

In order to avoid further mistakes, best practice is encoding text before using it in a URL like this:

```
$url = "http://" . $domain . "/whatever.php?text=" . urlencode($text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Send decoded url and get $_GET['email']

```
urlencode('test+email@gmail.com');
```

Comment: $url = "http://domain/index.php?email=".urlencode($path);      when you get the email then you will get email with + sign

Answer (score 1):

Space characters are encoded as "+" in application/x-www-form-urlencoded key-value pairs.

The RFC-1866 (HTML 2.0 specification), paragraph 8.2.1. subparagraph 1. says: "The form field names and values are escaped: space characters are replaced by `+', and then reserved characters are escaped").

Thus, while decoding the URLs, pluses are decoded back to spaces. For example, in your URL.

If you construct this URL using PHP, please call urlencode() on each of the key/value pairs, don't concatenate strings unencoded.

```
http://test.com/reservations/?email=test+parkos@gmail.com&number=GH76G
```

email will become

```
test parkos@gmail.com
```

to prevent it, make sure that the '+' characters in the URL are percent-encoded correctly, so the correct URL should be the following:

```
http://test.com/reservations/?email=test%2Bparkos@gmail.com&number=GH76G
```