# Escape encoding while parsing query parameter android

Tags: java, android, uri

I have an uri, whose parameter is like this,

> id=ahshshs+24
>   When I am parsing the parameter by,

```
String id = uri.getQueryParameter("id");
```

I am getting the response as

> ahshshs 24

The '+' is replaced by a space. I know this is because the uri gets encoded and it gets replaced. Is there a way, so as to get the value, without encoding?

Comment: While forming the URI, instead of using +, encode it, so that you could decode it later and interpret it as a + instead of a space. You can use `%2B` to encode it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses, I had done it using UrlQuerySanitizer.
Writing the code here.
First, I extended the UrlQuerySanitizer class as

```
public class CustomUrlQuerySanitizer extends UrlQuerySanitizer {
    @Override
    protected void parseEntry(String parameter, String value) {
//        String unescapedParameter = unescape(parameter);
        ValueSanitizer valueSanitizer =
                getEffectiveValueSanitizer(parameter);

        if (valueSanitizer == null) {
            return;
        }
//        String unescapedValue = unescape(value);
        String sanitizedValue = valueSanitizer.sanitize(value);
        addSanitizedEntry(parameter, sanitizedValue);
    }
}
```

Then, parsed the url as,

```
String id = null;
if (uri != null) {
    UrlQuerySanitizer urlQuerySanitizer = new CustomUrlQuerySanitizer();

    urlQuerySanitizer.registerParameter("id",
            new UrlQuerySanitizer.IllegalCharacterValueSanitizer(
                    UrlQuerySanitizer.IllegalCharacterValueSanitizer.ALL_OK
            ));
    urlQuerySanitizer.parseUrl(uri.toString());
    id = urlQuerySanitizer.getValue("id");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use %2B  instead  + symbol

so parameter should be like  Dahshshs%2B24

More details [Characters and symbols](http://ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

Answer (score 0):

While creating the URL encode it using `%2B`.

Refer [link](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) which states :

> Space characters are replaced by `+'

A related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005676/urls-and-plus-signs), which has a lot more details on a similar topic (URL encoding)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you had to encode your URL using java.net.URLEncoder.

```
String encodedParameter = URLEncoder.encode(paramToEncode, codification);
```

For example:

```
String encodedParameter = URLEncoder.encode("+", "UTF-8");
```

In this case, `+` will be encoded as `%2B`