# Timestamp shows without '+' symbol and replaces '+' symbol with space in Jmeter/Blazemeter recording

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

Timestamp shows without '+' symbol and replaces '+' symbol with space in Jmeter/Blazemeter recording. How to make it work/dynamically consider '+' always in the space when performing load test.

The current Blazemeter recording of our app search shows below POST call payload with time stamp value:
"to":"2017-12-20T10:42:08 05:30"

can observe in the above after 08 there is space whereas it should be 08+5:30.

on the browser shows correctly with + symbol. Please suggest how to make it always considering 08+5:30 when run for more users.

If run the script without + symbol getting 500 error, ,after manually changing able to get 200 code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` used as a space only in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content, such as the query part of a URL. see [URL and plus signs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005676/urls-and-plus-signs).

You try to compare values before (with +) and after URL decoding (without +)

Comment: Thanks for guiding. The content-type is going/recorded as applicaiton/json not application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: You can decode the value which will remove also the + signs `java.net.URLDecoder.decode(timestampValue, "UTF-8")); `

Comment: Thanks for guiding.