# Plus sign decoded into space

Tags: php, phalcon

I send requests from ios and android to some PHP server and some params in GET request are wrongly decoded.

```
request: http://myserver.com/path?email=john+doe

$_GET['email'] == 'john doe' instead of 'john+doe'
$this->request->get('email') == 'john doe' instead of 'john+doe'
```

Obviously php (I'm using phalcon) is using urldecode and replace + with 1 space.

How can avoid this? Can I change the type of enconding and "Content-Type" header accordingly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URLs and plus signs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005676/urls-and-plus-signs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> are wrongly decoded

They are **correctly** decoded.

> Can I change the type of enconding and "Content-Type" header accordingly?

No. The Content-Type header describes the format of the request body, not the query string.

You should encode the data in the query string correctly in the first place.

A `+` sign should be represented as `%2B`.

Answer (score 3):

If you really needed the '+' sign in the PHP file, you may need to have the '+' as '%2B'.

There is nothing wrong in reading the values which you mentioned.