# C# - Decoding a string does not return the original encoded one

Tags: c#, encoding, urlencode, urldecode

I have a random generated string that I need to put it in a URL, so I encode it like this:

```
var encodedToken = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(token, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

In an ASP.NET action method, I receive this token and decode it:

```
var token = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encodedToken, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

but these tokens are not the same. For example the `ab+cd` string would encode to `ab%2bcd` and decoding the result would give me the `ab cd` string (the plus character changed to whitespace).

So far I have only noticed the `+` character problem, there may be others.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1005676

Comment: The treatment of the + sign is described [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: @Igor I just tried `HttpUtility.UrlDecode("ab%2bcd")` in an Immediate Window and it's returning `ab+cd`. I don't know why in action method I get whitespace.

Comment: @mjwills You were right. I was double decoding. I checked the token at the beginning of action method and it had been already decoded.  You can post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your context, it appears that you don't need to call `UrlDecode` (since `%2b` decodes to `+` and `+` decodes to a blank space - i.e. you have double decoded).

Given, the framework appears to have already decoded it for you, you may remove your use of `UrlDecode`.

Comment: @panpawel If that is true, it must be a bug. Url decoding + should definitely result in space. Can you point me to a repro?

Answer (score -1):

According to the Microsoft documentation:

> You can encode a URL using with the UrlEncode method or the UrlPathEncode method. However, the methods return different results. The UrlEncode method converts each space character to a plus character (+). The UrlPathEncode method converts each space character into the string "%20", which represents a space in hexadecimal notation. Use the UrlPathEncode method when you encode the path portion of a URL in order to guarantee a consistent decoded URL, regardless of which platform or browser performs the decoding.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Yes, I linked to that page in my comment, above.