# Why when I send to a server keywords=C++ server drops plus signs?

Tags: sql, node.js

I'm using Node.js and I found out that when I send `GET` call to a server with `C++` then in SQL binding I get `C(blank space)(bankspace)` (checked with `console.log(req.query.keywords)` so essentialy the same length of the string, but no chars there.

When I use `SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE keywords LIKE' %c++%';` it works normally and gives me results. Is there something I don't know about Node - like it's dropping signs like `+`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URLs and plus signs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005676/urls-and-plus-signs)

Comment: True, didn't know how to ask that question before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue you're having is the same one outlined here: [URLs and plus signs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005676/urls-and-plus-signs)

The issue is that a GET is going to use the query string in the URL and plus signs need to be formatted (or encoded) similar to how a space is formatted as %20 in URLs. You could probably use or create a UrlEncoding method in your application.

In Node, I believe you can use something like: `encodeURIComponent('C++')`

The URL encoding for + is %2B

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure how to ask about this - now it's all clear :)