# Django query param get stripped if there is (+) sign

Tags: django, url

Whenever I try to to get my query string parameter everything works but only + sign gets stripped.

Here is url file:

```
urlpatterns = [
re_path(r'^forecast/(?P<city>[\w|\W]+)/$', weather_service_api_views.getCurrentWeather)]
```

Here is view File:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def getCurrentWeather(request, city):
   at = request.GET["at"]
   print(at)

   return JsonResponse({"status": "ok"}, status=200)
```

So if I hit the server with this URL:

**http://192.168.0.5:8282/forecast/Bangladesh/?at=2018-10-14T14:34:40+0100**

the output of at is like this:

**2018-10-14T14:34:40 0100**

Always + sign gets stripped. No other characters get stripped. I have used characters like !, = , - etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plus sign in query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855624/plus-sign-in-query-string) Also: [Does a `+` in a URL scheme/host/path represent a space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005676/does-a-in-a-url-scheme-host-path-represent-a-space).

Comment: Yes but partially. How to resolve the issue in Django?

Comment: As answers to those questions state you need to urlencode the `+` to be `%2B`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have done another solution based on the solution you provided. URL encoding for me right now will be a heavy task.

Comment: urlencoding is not a very difficult task... for curl: [How to urlencode data for curl command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/how-to-urlencode-data-for-curl-command). Please research a bit before asking any question...

Answer (score 1):

Since `+` is a special character, you will have to encode your value. Where to encode? it depends how are you generating the values for `at`. Based on your URL's and endpoints it looks like you are working on a weather app and `at` value is generated by Javascript. You can encode your values with [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```js
let at = encodeURIComponent(<your_existing_logic>)
```

eg:

```js
let at = encodeURIComponent('2018-10-14T14:34:40+0100')
```

it will return a result

> '2018-10-14T14%3A34%3A40%2B0100'

then in your backend you can get that value with:
`at = request.GET.get('at')`
it will give you the desired value, `2018-10-14T14:34:40+0100` in this case.

If you are creating your `at` param in your backend, then there are multiple ways to achieve that. You can look into this solution:
[How to percent-encode URL parameters in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695183/how-to-percent-encode-url-parameters-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for explaining. However I am using curl and this data can be given on terminal. So I assume there is no way to encode URL param in curl.

Comment: check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/how-to-urlencode-data-for-curl-command